# If condition for time range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to change the order amount based on the order delivery time, in my rails app. For this, I have modified my order_controller like this:

```
  class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def process_order
    @order = current_order
    if (@order.delievery_time[(4i), (5i)].between?('22:00', '00:30')) 
      @order.total = @order.total + @@mnc 
    end 
  end
  end
```

Here, when user submits delivery time between 2200hrs to 0030hrs, 'total' field should be 
(total = total + 50). And this total value should be submitted.

But giving 'syntax error on [(4i), (5i)]' error.

As I see in error log, it is displayed like this:

```
 "delievery_time(1i)"=>"2013",
 "delievery_time(2i)"=>"4",
 "delievery_time(3i)"=>"9",
 "delievery_time(4i)"=>"23",
 "delievery_time(5i)"=>"00",
```

I am interested in last two values only. How to get this work?
Can anybody help?

Comment: You'd need to have a value in `delievery_time`, obviously you don't at the moment. I'd also recommend spelling it correctly to avoid confusion. Also, adding a number to a symbol is non-sensical, you need to use the attribute's *value*, not its name.

Comment: @DaveNewton ohk. Got it. Will check on this.

Comment: @DaveNewton hey updated question. Can u help here?

Comment: Don't just use random code. `delievery_time` is a (time? date? Can't see your DB from here) so you need to use the methods defined on whatever type it is. And, please spell it right.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is time. In schema, delivery_time is like this: t.time "delivery_time". And in form, i am taking value like this: <%= f.time_select :delivery_time, {:default => 5.hours.from_now, :minute_step => 5, :ampm => true}, {:class=>"input-small"} %>

Comment: @DaveNewton hey just found that, delivery_time is submitting like this: 2013-04-09 23:00:00 UTC. Cause of thid code:  <%= f.time_select :delivery_time, {:default => 5.hours.from_now, :minute_step => 5, :ampm => true}, {:class=>"input-small"} %> How to make it submit like: 23.00?

Comment: You're using the standard Rails time entry, so that's the way it'll submit, and that's fine. I'd suggest reading some of the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming delivery_time is of class `Time` (or something compatible like Rails `TimeWithZone`), you can access the hours and minutes like this:

```
delivery_time = Time.new(2013, 4, 9, 23, 00)

puts delivery_time.hour   #=> 23
puts delivery_time.min    #=> 0
```

Comment: puts delivery_time.hour doesnt give anything but <%= delivery_time %> prints 2013-04-09 23:00:00 UTC

Comment: If `@order.delivery_time` gives nothing in your controller but shows a time in the view, then the value of `@order` must be different between the two. Add this to your view: `<%= debug @order %>`. Add this to your controller method: `puts @order.to_yaml`. Compare. I'm guessing that `current_order` doesn't return the value you'd like. Share more of your code here or create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [pastie](http://pastie.org/) or github repo so we can help.