# Time format while submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, time-select

I have a form input code like this:

```
 <%= f.time_select :delivery_time, {:default => 5.hours.from_now, :minute_step => 5, :ampm => true}, {:class=>"input-small"} %>
```

This is submitting value like: 2013-04-09 23:00:00 UTC

But i want value like : 23:00 as need define condition on time irrespective of date. I tried doing something like:

```
    if (@order.delivery_time.between?('21:00', '00:00')) 
      @order.total = @order.total + @@mnc 
    end
```

But It gives error as delivery_time is nil:class. But when print delivery_time it prints : 2013-04-09 23:00:00 UTC.

Not getting how to get it work. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: if condition for time range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906657/rails-if-condition-for-time-range)

Comment: @DaveNewton can u tell solution of issue?

Comment: [Pass something to `between?` it can actually use?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F) I don't know why your `delivery_time` is nil, I somewhat doubt it is since you can print it (you say). It could be how you build the object, I have no idea.

Comment: hmmm. In database it enters value, 23:00, and in print it gives like 2013-04-09 23:00:00 UTC. As per API, tried :ignore_date, but gives multiassignment error. Not getting how can i compare delivery_time falls in given range or no.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably conjure some date values so that you could call `#between?`. It would be simpler and more intention-revealing to extract just the part of the date you need to compare.

```
def late_order?(time)
  time.hour > 21
end

delivery_time = Time.new(2012, 1, 1, 22)
total = 300
total += 75 if late_order?(delivery_time)

puts "total for order: #{total}"   #=> 375
```